# DateTimePicker to restrict by Year choices in dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Is it possible to restrict `DateTimePicker` only by year choices when dropping down the calendar?

Comment: Are you trying to pick a Year or restrict the selection to a date within a given year?

Comment: Im trying to restrict the selection of a calendar form in when you drop it down by year choices only. Just like when you are picking a year in the calendar form not by UpDown control sir.

Comment: The control is a `DateTimePicker`, it always allows the selection of an entire, valid date.  If you just want the user to pick a year, why not use a ComboBox (or NumericupDown or DomainUpDown)?   The DTP doesnt work the way you want it to.

Comment: @Roelzkie...as @Plutonix said "The DTP doesnt work the way you want it to". You should set a custom format like `yyyy` and use `ShowUpDown` property to show just year. as I point in my answer.

Comment: Yes sir, but if there is no possibility then is there any way to just simply show the year selection in the calendar first? with this i could cover the monthly calendar.

Comment: Doing what @user2946329 gives in his answer is as close to a Year Picker as you are going to get using a DTP (and it will still return a full Date).  I say again, if all you want is the Year, why not use a ComboBox?  A DTP will likely confuse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following steps:

- Change the property of the `DateTimePicker`'s `Format` to `Custom` like this:

  ```
  dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
  ```
- Change the `CustomFormat` to `yyyy` like this:

  ```
  dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy";
  ```
- Set the `ShowUpDown` property to `true` or `false` as you want like this:

  ```
  dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
  ```